# Alternative to ClientLogin for authentication

Tags: google-api, gdata-api

Since Google lists the ClientLogin API as deprecated what is the recommended alternative?
In my case I need a server to authenticate and post things using credentials which I own. Alternatives like OAuth won't work in this context

Answer (score 0):

The authentication method varies based on the scenario of your application. The scenarios reported by [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) are:

- Login
- Web Server Applications
- Client-side Applications
- Installed Applications Devices
- Service Accounts

In your case, the Web Server Application scenario might be useful (if you give more details about what do you mean for "In my case I need a server to authenticate" I can be more precise about this point).

However, the recommended alternative to ClientLogin is [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).